# Android Material Ripples

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to follow [material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/) in my application. For tappable text should I use unbounded or bounded surface ink ripples (displayed when the user presses on the text)?

Comment: Could you add more details and make the question more clear! Do you want to know if you should do bounded or unbounded ripple or how to implement this features on your app?

Answer (score 0):

I used this Custom ripple layout for myself, I think it is easy to use:

[RippleLayout](https://github.com/BabakArtApps/CustomRipplaLayout/blob/master/RippleLayout.java)

and you can use it like this in your xml file:

```
                <your.package.name.RippleLayout
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                   app:mrl_rippleSelectedColorState="@android:color/transparent">

                   <!-- other views like buttons and.... -->
</your.package.name.RippleLayout>
```